# VBA Excel macro to quit all workbooks ends in infinite loop

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a macro to loop throuht all excel workbooks (in multiple instances) and print the active sheet in all workbooks and close all excel instances.

The code is following:

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If xl Is Nothing Then
    msgbox "Unable to set xl"
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim loopCount As Integer
loopCount = 0


Do Until xl Is Nothing
    loopCount = loopCount + 1

    For Each wb In xl.Workbooks
        wb.ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        wb.Saved = True
    Next

    xl.Quit

    If loopCount > 30 Then
        msgbox "Infinite loop"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

Loop

msgbox "Ended successfully"
```

The problem is, that only one application is quited and then macro end in an infinite loop. Why? I tried several ways hot to do it, always ending with infinite loop.

Thank you very much for your ideas!

Answer (score 1):

you close excel completly, so the macro can not end its work.

try this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If xl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Unable to set xl"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim loopCount As Integer
    loopCount = 0


    Do Until xl Is Nothing
        loopCount = loopCount + 1

        For Each wb In xl.Workbooks
            wb.ActiveSheet.PrintOut
            wb.Saved = True
            ' closes all workbooks except the one which contains the macro
            If (wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name) Then
                wb.Close
            ' if all workbooks except the one which contains the macro are closed, it junps to the end
            ElseIf (Workbooks.Count = 1) Then
                GoTo end
            End If
        Next



        If loopCount > 30 Then
            MsgBox "Infinite loop"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    Loop



    ' due to if (false) this part is just reachable via GoTo
    If (False) Then
end:
    ' here you can also close the workbook which contains the macro
    MsgBox "Ended successfully"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this solution does not deal with the problem of multiple excel instances running. Tested situation: 3 excel instances, each with one workbook. Result: Macro ends immediatelly as there is only one workbook in its instance.

Comment: You are right, i am sorry. Accidentally i read over "...workbooks (in multiple instances) and...". unfortunately i do not have a quick answer for the multiple intances problem...

Comment: Hi, excuse me for the late answer. I could not find a way to manipulate a sheet in an other excel instance. sry i can not help you with this spezific problem.